# Is it possible to determine location by triangulation using radio waves?

Tags: rf

I have a project in mind which consists of multiple beacons and a device. A device broadcasts a signal every n seconds, and once the signal is received by the beacons they respond with their unique id. Then some fixed delay caused by inner components of beacon is subtracted and time to reach the beacon and returned to the device and used to calculate distance. Multiple beacons would allow for more precise positioning.

The range I have in mind is about 200 meters maximum from the device to beacon. I hope to achieve a precision (with error margin) of a meter or two.

I know that similar a technique is used by cell towers. Here lies the source of my confusion. As far as I know, cell towers use electro magnetic wavees which travel at the speed of light. With such speed, it seems impossible to measure time taken accurately enough to obtain any reasonable precision. What's more, I want to ensure the beacons are affordable so I set my sights on Attiny microcontroller family to control the beacons, which further limits the processing speed.

Yet, cell towers are quite accurate at determining the location. So is GPS, which while it uses the time between consequetive satellite broadcasts to determine the position also relies on electro magnetic waves for communication.

How is it done? I've seen plenty of examples using sound waves, but I'm not sure how far they can reach, and how inteference resistant that setup would be.

I'm a bit confused on the matter since radio waves travel at light speed, I'm doubting it is possible to use them in a system consisting of beacons.

Comment: I think you might mean trilateration rather than triangulation. *So how is it done?* <-- armed with the proper name you should be able to google that because it isn't really an EE question.

Comment: Distances are usually calculated through RSSI, not by measuring the propagation delay.

Comment: Does this article help you? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loran-C

Comment: @Andyaka thanks, you are right. It seems that's the proper term, and googling it does look more promising.

Comment: @HerbalTea:  GPS does not use the time between between broadcasts from the satellites to determine position.  Each broadcast includes the time at which it was sent.  You determine when you received it and find the difference to the time it was sent.  That difference tells you the distance -  with only one received packet from the satellite.

Comment: Your system sounds very complicated.  Each object to track needs a transmitter and a receiver.  Each beacon needs a transmitter and a receiver.    You will be limited in how many devices can measure their position by the time it takes for each beacon to respond.

Comment: "With such speed, it seems impossible to measure time taken accurately enough to obtain any reasonable precision." - it is certainly possible, but not with the resolution you want and not with any equipment you could build. Old cell towers (GSM) already did exactly what you describe, with a resolution of 1.8 microseconds (550 meters). 5G can do it with a 10 meter accuracy.

Comment: 1 meter of precision at the speed of light is about 3 nanoseconds, I think it's beyond the level of what you can get from homemade DIY circuits

Comment: Something vaguely similar has been around for decades for aircraft: [VOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHF_omnidirectional_range).

Comment: Remember that light speed is finite! It's really fast, sure, but it's not infinite. You can do temporal measurements with light-speed signals.

Comment: One of option would be to compare time with pre programed time delay. You can get them in 10 ps resolution (for example SY100EP195V). So you could measure signal round trip time. I am not sure if this is also practically possible.